# 404 error while handling POST requests in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

js and express, below is the route handler file :

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var authRoutes = App.route('authRoutes');
var sessionRoutes = App.route('sessionRoutes');
var userRoutes = App.route('userRoutes');


var invalidUserError = App.middleware('invalidUserError');
var validateNewUser = App.middleware('validateNewUser');


function AuthRoutes(app){
    var Authrouter = express.Router();
    Authrouter.route('/signIn')
        .get(authRoutes.signIn)
        .post(validateNewUser, userRoutes.create,invalidUserError);

    Authrouter.route('/signUp')
        .get(authRoutes.signUp)
        .post(passport.authenticate(
            'local', 
             { successRedirect : '/portal' },        
             { failureRedirect : '/auth/signIn' }
        ));

    app.use('/auth',Authrouter);
}
module.exports = AuthRoutes;
```

I am able to handle the get request properly but when i do a POST request to the /signIn url i am getting a 404 not found response please help.

Comment: Are you using body parser for your post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you need in your URL is `/auth/signIn` because you mounted the `Authrouter` with the `/auth` prefix.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out , Thanks :)